# Unknown error regarding mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, fuelphp

I was using Fuelphp's older version, now I am using 1.8 latest. After I upgraded the core and bootstrap files, I have php 7 and mysql latest installed works fine, php and mysql.

> Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 42000 ]:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0' at line 12 with query: "SELECT DISTINCT(i.p_id) as product_id,p.*,p.id as pid, c.title as cat_title, p.title as title, i.price as price from products p LEFT JOIN categories c on c.id=p.category_id LEFT JOIN inventories i on i.p_id = p.id LEFT JOIN users u on u.id=p.from_id WHERE (p.status=1 AND c.status=1 AND i.instock>0 AND p.id = ) GROUP BY product_id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0"

This is the exact error message. The same project in other computer runs perfectly but here it display's this error. See at last of error, **AND p.id = )** but in other PC, it runs perfectly. In other PCs, I have PHP 5 in one and PHP 7 in one, and 1.8 fuelphp. I am just curious, why is this error being displayed. Is something missing on Mysql side like query substitution or similar like that?

Comment: You need to actually pass a value to the query to check against p.id, even if it's null or `''`. Check your code to find out why that value isn't being passed in.

Comment: Code may run fine; but if data varies you could have an issue.  such as the manner in which you define p.id may be attempting to get a product that isn't in this db, but is in the one that's working.

Comment: Actually, the same code I copy and pasted works on another PC. so, the value has been passed in another but not in  mine. and as i changed my php version, it worked. thats strange.